# CodeMirror annotating

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes, react-codemirror, ui-codemirror

I want to give markup style input to a CodeMirror component, but only use that markup to indicate that I want to create an interactive hover component out of it.

So for example, if the input value for code mirror is:

```
This is a <foo param1="bar">test</foo> sentence
```

I want it to just render "This is a test sentence", but allow the user to hover over "test" and see a pop-up in context with the parameters provided.

How might this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this using Atomic Ranges:

[https://codemirror.net/examples/decoration/#underlining-command:~:text=stripe%20example.-,Atomic%20Ranges,-In%20some%20cases](https://codemirror.net/examples/decoration/#underlining-command:%7E:text=stripe%20example.-,Atomic%20Ranges,-In%20some%20cases)